erreur pnpm install: ERR_PNPM_EIO Failed to add tarball
how i can resolve the error
 ERR_PNPM_EIO  Failed to add tarball from "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query/-/eslint-plugin-query-5.32.1.tgz" to store: EIO: i/o error, open '/media/user/TOSHIBA/.pnpm-store/v3/files/fe/46447fbf0a8cde01dbb9d21b962e5161708881be7380f624a9012b62d1f19dfe61ebf9e4eb1027427af75a8f843271f524158f5143df11dc49e8d02a7a147d26728'

Maybe your hard drive is on the way out, or the path got too long for the file system you use.

I put my project from my external hard drive to internal (my computer) and as long as I have the Linux min operating system while Linux is sensitive I have to give authorization each time what I put it in /home for not giving me authorized access and there I solved the problem
